# Retrieving data from large MySQL table using C++ / cppconn

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

I have got a table with approximately 100 millions rows in my mySQL database - which I want to export into a different format.

I am using libmysqlcppconn7 to connect from C++ to the DB. When running the query like the following, the process is eating up all my memory:

```
unique_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> statement(getConnection()->prepareStatement(
    "SELECT " + joinedColumnNames + " FROM " + table
));
unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet> queryResult(statement->executeQuery());
while (queryResult->next()) {
    // process columns and store them elsewhere
}
```

That is because the above code tries to load the whole table in memory. I would like to read line-by-line instead. I found `FLAG_NO_CACHE` and php's `mysql_use_result` but I can't find anything for the libcppconn.

How do I do this in C++?

My current work-around is to first `SELECT count(*) FROM table` and then to fetch 1 million rows a time using `LIMIT start,1000000` in the query. That works but doesn't feel right.

Comment: Why you don't like to fetch 1 million rows a time? is the best solution IMO. Many graphical tool (ORACLE SQLDeveloper, TOAD, ....) use the same solution

Comment: Because I first tried it with 10k rows a time and the whole thing was slow as hell: for the first part of the table it was ok, but then is was becoming slower and slower until I have cancelled the whould query an hour (when maybe 30% had been processed). With 1M rows I was done processing the whole table in approx 1 hour. I thought there had to be a better solution!

Comment: What is the time you spend _processing_ records and what the time you spend to _fetch_ the records?

Comment: processing the records is quite fast, fetching isn't. Maybe it is important to note that the table I am fetching the data from is actually a VIEW (it joins 2 different tables) and my fear is that when fetching elements 1000001 to 2000000, mySQL first has to calculate also elemens 1-1000000 to be able to know where to start with the 1-million-and-first element.

Comment: I don't know well MySQL. In the past I worked with ORACLE and I solved problems related to views using **Materialized Views** (not supported in MySQL). ORACLE also allows to use **host arrays** to improve the performace in loading/sending records